# MYSQL create "complex" view

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, sql-view

So I'm trying to make a website for my friends and me. In that site I have a form to start "wars". When you submit the form it saves into a table with the fields "attacker" and "victim". I also have another table named accounts so they can login to the site. This other table has an "id" column, "discord_id", and "username". How can I create a MYSQL view to have all columns like this:
**ACCOUNTS:**

```
+----+----------+----------------+------------+
| id | username |    password    | discord_id |
+----+----------+----------------+------------+
|  1 | user1    | users2password |  users1id  |
|  2 | user2    | users2password |  users2id  |
+----+----------+----------------+------------+
```

**WARS:**

```
+--------+-------------+-----------+
| war_id | attacker_id | victim_id | 
+--------+-------------+-----------+
|      1 |           1 |      2    |
|      2 |           2 |      1    |
+--------+-------------+-----------+
```

**RESULT I WANT:**

```
+--------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+
| war_id | attacker_id | attacker_discor_id| attacker_username | victim_id | victim_discord_id | victim_username |
+--------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+
|      1 |           1 | users1discordi    | user1             |         2 |    user2discordid | user2           |
|      2 |           2 |  ...              |    ...            |   ...     |       ...         |   ...           |
+--------+-------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Also, I'm quite a noob, so I don't know if I gave all the necessary information. If you need another information, ask it and I'll answer as soon as I can.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you made any attempts yourself so far?

Comment: Hopefully `password` values are just an example here. Passwords should never be stored as plain text.

Comment: @NigelRen, I've tried but I coudn't, GMB gave the answer that helped me.
Thankss

Comment: @user3783243, they are hashed! Don't worry! Thanksss

Comment: You should include any attempts, some people will give help but it is supposed to be help and not do the job for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the `wars` table, you can join the `accounts` table twice, once for the attacker and another for the victim - the trick is to give different aliases to each joined table, so you can unambiguously refer to their columns:

```
create view wars_view as
select w.war_id, 
    w.attacker_id, a1.discord_id attacker_discord_id, a1.username attacker_username,
    w.victim_id,   a2.discord_id victim_discord_id,   a2.username victim_username
from wars w
inner join accounts a1 on a1.id = w.attacker_id
inner join accounts a2 on a2.id = w.victim_id
```